# Как сделать так чтобы расширение Chrome подгружалось после загрузки Dom страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, расширения

В расширение используются переменные которые определяются только после полного загрузки Dom.
Как сделать чтобы мой скрипт загружался только после появления этих переменных?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
$(window).load(function() {
/* код будет запущен тогда, когда страница будет полностью загружена */
});
```